# Setting up s.campaign parameter string in adobe DTM

Tags: url-parameters, adobe-analytics

I am trying to set `s.campaign` via Adobe DTM using the google analytics parameters which would look like this:

```
s.campaign=s.getQueryParam('utm_source,utm_medium,utm_term,utm_campaign',':');
```

However I can't get this to work via DTM implementation where I have the `s.campaign` dropdown to "query param" and have this typed:

> utm_source,utm_medium,utm_term,utm_campaign,:

Am I missing some syntax? Do I need that in DTM?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do it directly in the DTM interface, I don't believe it will let you do multiple parameters at once like that- it's expecting just something like "cid". It may be that the easiest way to accomplish what you're trying to accomplish would be to keep the getQueryParam plugin that you have and just add it to your library (s_code) or your Adobe Analytics tool Custom Code in DTM.